# Plagiarism detection software – comparing two long documents

Tags: plagiarism, software

I would like to find out whether one of two long documents plagiarises the other. I’m looking for software or a website that does this but does not store the documents on the server (i.e., the documents should be kept private if possible).  Does such a software exist?

Note that I’m not looking to compare to millions of possible documents, so I don’t need a service like TurnItIn.

Comment: You can see my answer [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/8466/2692). There is a link to a piece of software that will work well for this purpose. In fact, I think this question is really a duplicate of that question.